# Perform conditional render operations on mapped data - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am mapping data within the returned render, but I am wanting to then perform a conditional on the data that has been mapped... Is it possible to do something like this?

```
export default function App() {
  const prod = [
    {'name': '1'},
    {'name': '2'},
    {'name': '3'}
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {prod && (
        <div>
          {prod.map(p => (

            // This is the point I get an error
            {p.name === '1' && (
              <h1>This is 1</h1>
            )}

          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Currently I am getting an error:

```
Unexpected token, expected "," (16:14)

  14 |         <div>
  15 |           {prod.map(p => (
> 16 |             {p.name === '1' && (
     |               ^
```

Comment: try with this `{p.name === '1' ? (<h1>This is 1</h1>): <></>}`

Comment: Remove the curly braces around `p.name && ...` ---> `{prod.map((p) => p.name === "1" && <h1>This is 1</h1>)}</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions with the format `x => ()` return the content of the brackets.

So you are returning what the compiler thinks is an object, as it's wrapped in curly brackets `x => ({ ... })` You need to remove the braces:

```
prod.map(p => (
    p.name === '1' && <h1>This is 1</h1>
)
```

Or explicitly return the value:

```
prod.map(p => {
    return p.name === '1' && <h1>This is 1</h1>
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I knew there was something obvious I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map the data for any specific index then you can check this.

```
<div>
    {prod.map(p => p.name === '1' && <h1>Conditionally Mapped</h1> || <h1>Normally mapped</h1>}
</div>

// similar to the previous one

<div>
    {prod.map(p => {
      if(p.name === '1') return <h1>Conditionally Mapped</h1>
      else return <h1>Normally mapped</h1>
    }

</div>
```